# R: Matrix multiplication error - related to GLM

Tags: r, glm

I've been trying to build some custom code for Logistic regression (i.e. I cannot use the GLM package for this purpose since - happy to explain why.)

Below is the initial R code to provide the data set I'm working with:

```
## Load the datasets
data("titanic_train")
data("titanic_test")

## Combining Training and Testing dataset
complete_data <- rbind(titanic_train, titanic_test)

library(dplyr)
titanic_test$Survived <- 2
complete_data <- rbind(titanic_train, titanic_test)
complete_data$Embarked[complete_data$Embarked==""] <- "S"
complete_data$Age[is.na(complete_data$Age)] <- 
median(complete_data$Age,na.rm=T)
complete_data <- as.data.frame(complete_data)
titanic_data <- select(complete_data,-c(Cabin, PassengerId, Ticket, 
Name))

titanic_data <- titanic_data[!titanic_data$Survived == "2", ]

titanic_model <- model <- glm(Survived 
~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=titanic_data)


y <- titanic_data$Survived
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(rep(1, dim(titanic_data) 
[1]),titanic_data[,-2]))
x <- as.matrix(as.numeric(x))

beta <- as.numeric(rep(0, dim(x)[2]))
beta <- as.matrix(beta)
```

The issue I'm having here is **I would like to compute the matrix product** of **beta** (a px1 matrix) and **x** (a n x p matrix)

I have tried the following -

```
beta * x
x %*% beta
```

However, the above the following errors -

> Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   Error in x %*% beta : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I'd imagine this is due to the fact I've got non-numeric fields in the data matrix **x**.
As a bit of a background, **calculating the linear predictor will allow me to progress with my custom code for fitting a Logistic regression model.**
I would appreciate some help - thank you!

Comment: The dimensions don't work in that order. You need `x %*% beta`. When doing matrix multiplication the number *columns in the left* multiplier must equal the *number of rows* in the right multiplier. (Voting to close as typo.)

Comment: In general, when you ask about an error message you are getting, please include the error message. They are often very helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for pointing that out - apologies for that - it should have read exactly what you wrote. The issue still persists - I think it's because of the categorical variable(s) I have in the data matrix X.

Comment: A `matrix` cannot have a mixture of categorical and non-categorical variables. A matrix can only have one data type. Maybe you have a `data.frame`? Check `class(x)` to see what it is. A data frame is great for storing data, but you can't multiply categorical variables, you can only multiply numbers. You'll need to convert your data frame to an appropriate matrix before you can multiply. `model.matrix()` is the function usually used for that, it will convert categorical variables to dummy variables.

Comment: @Gregor - thank you very much! using the model.matrix method does help me resolve this issue. I will close this question as answered. Much appreciated.